# Searching array like below but it returns null

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some data which is an array of arrays, each sub-array is length one and the only item in that array is an object with key value pairs. As an example:

```
const array = [[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}], [{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}], ,[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]]
```

I am trying to loop through this array and pull out only the cities. I can do that by running

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0].city))
```

However, when I try this on my actual data (which I unfortunately cannot share) I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')
```

When I try to run just

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0]))
```

the only thing that gets returned is a bunch of [, plus one undefined for the blank entry.

If it is relevant, the actual data that I am trying to index into is a column pulled from a Google Sheet.

Does anyone know why I am unable to properly iterate through my data and any possible solutions around it?

As Parvez pointed out, my array is being pulled from the data as an array of strings, rather than an array of arrays. That means that my data actually looks like

```
const array = ["[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}]", "[{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}]", "","[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]"]
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how to work with those sub-arrays so that I can pull out the relevant data, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Most of the content of your question, including the title, is irrelevant - the 0th value is `[` because it's a string, **not** an array. So _parse the string_. I'd guess this is a re-post - actually edit it to reflect your current understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this.

```html
const array = [[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}], [{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}], ,[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]]


array.map((element)=> {
  const [{city, state}] = element;
  console.log(city)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer marked accepted (at the time of writing this paragraph) does not solve the issue with the input that is provided in the question. That answer has removed the double quotes, so that no string needs to be parsed anymore.

If we take your original input without change, we see strings in your data that need to be parsed. These strings have JavaScript notation and not JSON, which is a pity. If you control the source of the data it would be a good idea to make sure it has JSON compatible strings.

If not, then `eval` could help, but it has the major downside that it opens up the risk of code injection.

The compromise could be to use a parser that also accept single quote delimiters. There happens to be a popular library [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) that does that.

Here is a demo for your sample. Note that an empty string will not be considered valid input (as it is not JSON), so you need to deal with those yourself. Here I will translate those to `null`:

```html
<script type="module">

import JSON5 from 'https://unpkg.com/json5@2/dist/index.min.mjs'

const array = ["[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}]", "[{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}]", "","[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]"];
const result = array.map(s => s ? JSON5.parse(s) : null);
console.log(result);

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, @trincot. Heller Stern's answer is more powerful.

Comment: No problem. But it doesn't work with the input you provided in the question. They used different input. Note they removed the double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example array:

```
const array = ["[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}]", "[{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}]", "","[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]"]
```

You can hande the whole thing as a string... If that's not optimal you can still reuse the regex in a for loop or a map...

```
function getCities(array) {
    const cities = array.toString();
    const findCities = cities.match(/(?<='city': ')(.*?)(?=',)/g);
    return findCities;
}
```